# x-editable, how to show specific value when string is empty?

Tags: javascript, x-editable

I am trying to show a default value when a field is null or empty (string), and edit mode is disabled using x-editable.  Using the attribute "data-value" works great when the field or string is null, for example:

```
<b><a id="location_name" data-type="text" data-title="Location name" data-placeholder="Location" data-emptytext="Location" data-value="Location">@Model.geoLocation.location_name</a></b> <br />
```

However, if the string is empty (but not null), the data-value will not show.  I was wondering if there is a way to still show the default data-value if the string is empty (i.e., in addition to when it is null).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';     

    $('.confirm_assistance').editable({
        url: '<?php echo PATH; ?>controllers/administrator/insert/boardingListPax.php',
        emptytext: 'Text for empty/null value'
    });
});
</script>
```

The thing here is to use

```
        emptytext: 'Text for empty/null value'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just using || inside the a tag.

```
<a href="#" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to edit the emptytext all of the inputs you can do this.

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.emptytext = 'Text for empty/null value';

$.fn.editable.defaults.emptytext = '{{ 'Text for empty/null value' | trans | escape('js') }}';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).